# Batch finding a certain string in files and writing them into a txt file

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-scripting

I'm very new to batch scripting, and I'm trying to find an 11 digit number from a set of files within an ID named folder. I need the Folder ID number to be written into a txt file followed by the 11 digit number, basically like this:

```
ID1-12345678910
ID2-12345678911
ID3-12345678912
```

All ID named folders contain a unique 11 digit number, so I can't search for a specific number, the only criteria is that it is 11 digits. The folder hierarchy looks something like this:

```
ID1(folder)

  subfolder1

    subfolder2

      file1 (all these files within the same ID named folder contain the same 11 digit number, so file 1-5 all contain the same 11 digit number corresponding to the ID folder)
      file2
      file3
      file4
      file5

ID2
ID3
ID4
ID5
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: And exactly what is the question? Where is your batch and at what point does it fail. Once you tell to write and then file  1-5 contain the number? I'm puzzled. Please read what a [mcve] is. And don't expect other to put more effort in your task than you yourself.

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I would do something like using findstr to find all digits `findstr [0-9]` in a for loop with spaces as delimeter and put the numbers `123, 3141592, etc...` in a variable `set a=123` then do two checks, one `if not %a:~0,10% = %a%` to make sure it's at least 11 chars, then two `if %a:0,11% == %a%` to be sure it's only 11 chars.

Comment: wow those code thingies made a cool pyramid :)

Comment: though `findstr "[0-9][0-9][0-9]...."` 11 times might work better... but the other way kinda makes you look cool